# How to use a multi-module setup in maven?

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins, pom.xml, parent-pom

In Parent component, I am adding child modules inside  tag.

```
<!-- Parent pom.xml -->
<groupId>com.acc.app</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<modules>
 <module>../child1/pom.xml</module>
 <module>../child2.pom.xml</module>
</modules>
```

Where child1 and child2 are different packages outside Parent.

The purpose is that when I build parent, all children should also build automatically. In my local I am able to build Parent and all children but getting an error in Jenkins server.

Error: child1/pom.xml does not exist.
child2/pom.xml does not exist.

Comment: Please add (some relevant) error message, otherwise it is hard to guess/could be anything...

Comment: @xerx593 
Error: child1/pom.xml does not exist.
child2/pom.xml does not exist.

Comment: So I would investigate the "scm checkout" next.. (forgot to/any problems during: pull/push!?;) (You can [edit] question, if relevant/improves;)

Comment: There was not problems during pull/push. This is only failing in Jenkins not in local. Local it is able to pick pom.xmls from .m2 folder.

Comment: Modules need to be in the same git repository.

Comment: What if it is not? Childs are from different git repository.

Comment: If you don't have them in the same repo you should not use a multi module setup... apart from that using `../childxx.`is looking weirds... so if you like to build such things in Jenkins you have to checkout the other git repos via Jenkins ... I would make a single git repository and build that...